# whitespace handling with source control

Tags: svn, server, tortoisesvn, diff

This is not a duplicate question. When using tortoise svn/subversion the file system reports that files have changed and upon reviewing the only thing that may have changed will be a tab or a space. There is lots of documentation on using alternative merge tools such as winmerge but altering the actual diff engine. This isn't as much of an issue with c#/java as they have inbuilt formatters but without the use of redgate for SQL server this is a nightmare. My new client wants to enforce a standard of never using tabs over spaces. I could write something but it is fraught with complexities.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193271/can-cvs-and-subversion-be-set-to-ignore-whitespace-in-merging